# Non-simplicity of groups of order $p^{a}(p+1)$, $p$ a prime

Tags: group-theory

Alperin and Bell, Groups and Representations, section 7, exerc. 10 (a), p. 71, is as follows : if $p$ is a prime number, if $G$ is a group of order $p^{a}(p+1)$, with $a > 1$, then $G$ cannot be simple. It is stated at a little advanced stage of the theory (elementary properties of Sylow subgroups), but I don't find an easy proof. (If $a$ is equal to 1 or 2, it can be proved with use of Burnside's normal complement theorem.) I think it can be proved that the intersection of two Sylow subgroups of $G$ always has order $< p^{a-1}$ and from this it can be concluded that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p^{2}$, which gives a proof, but it seems a little difficult to me for an exercise without hint. Do you know an easier proof ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural action of $G$ on the cosets of a Sylow $p$-subgroup induces a homomorphism $\varphi: G \rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(p+1)$. If $G$ is simple, then $\varphi$ is injective. Since the largest power of $p$ dividing $(p+1)!$ is $p$, we have $a = 1$ if $G$ is simple.

And as you said, when $|G| = p(p+1)$ the claim follows from Burnside's normal complement theorem.

Comment: Thanks. Your reasoning is classical. It seems that I was not awake...